# how to save a linux kernel and modules for use in other distro

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

Long story short, I bought a pre-installed linux laptop and would like to be able to run other linux distros, but use the same linux drivers w/ other distro so as to have all my hardware work flawlessly as it does with the custom linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
   If I could save or copy all of my hardware drivers someplace to reinstall once I've got a new linux distro installed.
   So far I think the answer lays in compiling a linux kernel and modules from my running linux laptop, and try to get flashed in my new linux distro that I'm installing.   Not sure if that will work? or is the easiest method.
    Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
i just want my linux workstation hardware to work as good as it does w/ Ubuntu 14.04, with any linux distro I choose to try.
   Thanks in advance

Comment: To do so you will have to build your own kernel (with your drivers) and install this kernel with your drivers for each Linux distribution you are gonna use (because **version magic** should be the same in each driver as in your kernel image). Such an approach... seems quite weird for me. Most people prefer to use kernel images (and drivers) from distro repository. Because it's much more easier to support your system using distro package manager rather than build and install your custom stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will try to build my kernel w/ modules as you suggested. Further research and I think I could use the PPA's for Ubuntu and for my laptop manufacturer for updating device drivers.

Answer (score 0):

A bit weired, but, as far as I gnow:

- you can do the thing you ask for to customize the same distribution.
- "Compiling a linux kernel and modules from my running linux laptop": You said the running one, so You can pick it instead directly from "/boot/vmlinuz-KERNEL_VERSION
- "If I could save or copy all of my hardware driver": You can copy the content of "/lib/modules/KERNEL_VERSION" folder in the same emplacement in the target. This folder contains kernel modules, among others, device drivers.
- After having these in place, you can make the drivers working with "modprobe", you should have a list for all modules (you might use "lsmod" in the original system) and load them one by one or find a way that manage to load them all at once for you; in CentOS, there is a scrpit "/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit" that can among other stuffs, do that for you.

I really wonder why you are worried about drivers on Linux distributions, coz, as far as I know, they are really good when it comes to device drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Basically I got a new work laptop w/ a 4k touch screen display and quadro 1100 graphics card that came with Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to use the drivers for graphics, touch pad, 4k touch screen ect. in another linux Distro.  And I'm pretty sure that the linux Ubuntu drivers don't work properly w/o my laptop manufacturers proprietary devices drivers.         Thanks again will try your suggestion tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: In this case, since the Linux Kernel in other distributions have module support, try first to only copy the desired modules from "/lib/modules/KERNEL_VERSION" from the original to target, if you can just pick the desired modules, otherwise, merge that folder and don't replace the already existing modules. I hope it works.